# mobile barcode readers - where do they draw their information?

Tags: barcode

I'm pretty much a noob.  I've been wondering how mobile barcode readers worked.  I've seen several apps on the market that would let you scan a barcode, and then show you corresponding product data.

I was wondering where the product data typically comes from.  Is it usually from a built-in database, or do apps tend to connect to a server to access a database?

Thanks for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barcode readers/scanners work by using some sort of standard format to communicate data to the device 'reading' the code.  There are typically two types of 'barcodes' used today:

- The [standard Barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode) - often referred to as a UPS code
- And the [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) - popular for cell-phone apps.

From a developer's standpoint, both work the same way:

- A device 'reads' the code, the code is interpreted to represent a set of numbers (typical of the standard Barcode), or numbers and characters (QR code).
- The interpreted code is used to seek the related data in a database somewhere - A UPC code would have a database of items referenced with a number (just like the number you would read at the bottom of a UPC label), and a QR code frequently references a URL that can be opened in any web browser.

The information from a barcode comes from the referenced data that the barcode points to - so you don't have to carry around a database of information anytime you want to scan a code - you just have to be able to connect to that source of information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton for the very thorough answer!  I especially appreciate how you realized how little I knew about the topic, and went out of your way to provide additional information.  You, kind sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Cheers!

Comment: @user1504790 Not a problem, that's what we're here for.  Welcome to the site.